# get partial view points from 3d surface mesh

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I have a 3d surface mesh.

Say the camera is located in some points and I want to get the visible points from the 3d surface mesh from the camera view.

I believe this kind of process would be done before 3d rendering in graphics.

I want to know how it generally works and fast, simple algorithm for the problem. It would be better, if there is some matlab function library to do this task.

Note that 3d rendering is not my purpose... I just want to get the visible point set from the 3d surface mesh.

Comment: Its called frustum culling. You can accelerate this with spatial querries like bspor occtrees for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you would test every point to see if it lies inside your camera frustum, this is basically a set of point-vs-plane tests. This is not a fast way to do do things but the simplest to understand and implement.